# If $y^2 = x^2 + 9$ is not valid function then why $f(x)=\sqrt{x+2}$ is a valid function?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

the first equation since $y$ is squared then it will have two answers so it won't be a valid function.

But in the second one if i replace $x$ with $2$ for example then $f(x)$ will have $-2$ and $+2$ as an answer and yet it's a valid function.

Comment: Two issues: (a) domains and co-domains; (b) explicit and implicit functions

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/284179/why-is-y-sqrtx-4-a-function-and-y-sqrt4-x2-should-be-a-circle

Comment: $\sqrt{}$ was *explicitely* defined to be the *non-negative* square root.  So whereas the first equation will include both (4,-5) and (4, 5) as solutions, the second will include (2, 2) as a solution but it will NOT include (2, -2) as a solution as $\sqrt{4} = 2$ and $\sqrt{4} \ne -2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main thing is that you are suggesting $\sqrt{4}$ would be both $2$ and $-2$. That's not how it works. The symbol $\sqrt{x}$ always means the *positive* square root of a (positive real) number. If you want to consider both $2$ and $-2$, you'd write $\pm\sqrt{4}$.

Comment: you mean $\sqrt{4}$ is an absolute value when I am solving a function?

Comment: $\sqrt{4}$ is only equal to $2$. The symbol is the square root function.

Comment: $ \sqrt{x^2} = |x|$.  $\sqrt{x^2} \ne - |x|$.  $\sqrt{(-3)^2} = 3$.  $\sqrt{(-3)^2} \ne -3$.

Comment: I know this sounds stupid, but why I can't use $\pm\sqrt{4}$ as an answer for $f(x)$ in my example above?

Comment: @Tom Put $2$ in place of $x$, do you get $\pm\sqrt{4}$?

Comment: I got it, the problem is that I always learn in school that $\sqrt{4}$ answer is +2 or -2 not $\pm\sqrt{4}$

Comment: @Tom Your function is $f(x)=\sqrt{x+2}$. It doesn't say $f(x)=\pm\sqrt{x+2}$. So that is why $f(2)$ is just plain $4$, not $\pm4$. (And of course $f(x)=\pm\sqrt{x+2}$ would not be considered a valid function formula in the first place.)

Comment: @Tom Yes, students are improperly taught $x^2=4$ ${}\implies\sqrt{x^2}=\sqrt{4}$ ${}\implies x=\pm2$, which leads to your confusion. The correct version of that would be $x^2=4$ ${}\implies\sqrt{x^2}=\sqrt{4}$ ${}\implies |x|=2$ ${}\implies x=2\text{ or }-2$. (There is nothing mathematically wrong with the first version, but it skips a step that leads to this kind of misunderstanding.)

Answer (score 1):

$\sqrt{2+2}=2$. When we use the root sign, we refer to the positive square root only. So, the second one is indeed a function.

Answer (score 1):

The expression $\sqrt{x+2}$ has the implicitly assumes the postive result, while the equation $y^2 =  x^2 + 9$, which is the object that $f(x)$ parameterizes. The choice in the first case makes it a well defined function.